# How to limit rows on a window function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to get a result on one query.

```
with rws as (
select o.*, first_value(o.ACCT_ID) over(PARTITION by acct_id ORDER by acct_id asc) rn
from ACCT_PLAN o
)
select * from rws
where rn >= 10
and PLAN_STATUS_CD = 'ACTIVE'
order by acct_id;
```

So I need do get a following result. All rows are "grouped" by partition clause in the window function by acct_id in the CTE. In the main select I need to limit each ACCT_ID if they have more than 10 rows.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6rRL.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDOGe.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `COUNT` rather then find the `FIRST_VALUE` if you want to return partitions with 10 or more rows:

```sql
WITH rws AS (
  SELECT o.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION by acct_id ORDER by acct_id ASC) AS cnt
  FROM   ACCT_PLAN o
)
SELECT *
FROM   rws
WHERE  cnt >= 10
AND    PLAN_STATUS_CD = 'ACTIVE'
ORDER BY acct_id;
```

---

If, instead, you want to limit a partition to the first 10 rows, and then to those who are active, then use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH rws AS (
  SELECT o.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by acct_id ORDER by acct_id ASC) AS cnt
  FROM   ACCT_PLAN o
)
SELECT *
FROM   rws
WHERE  rn <= 10
AND    PLAN_STATUS_CD = 'ACTIVE'
ORDER BY acct_id;
```

Or if you want the first 10 active rows:

```sql
WITH rws AS (
  SELECT o.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by acct_id ORDER by acct_id ASC) AS cnt
  FROM   ACCT_PLAN o
  WHERE  PLAN_STATUS_CD = 'ACTIVE'
)
SELECT *
FROM   rws
WHERE  rn <= 10
ORDER BY acct_id;
```

Comment: actually i need to cut the result as i uploaded the second picture. with count it`s working but i got only numbers 10 and there are still 12 records for ID 1007

Comment: i need the IDs in the answer.Imagine that you have 12 rows for ID 1007 i need to show only 10 of them

Comment: @Jony_Junior Did you look at the edit I posted? That will give you at-most 10 rows for each partition

Comment: did it!
with rn as (SELECT ACCT_ID,RMAN_PYMT_CNT,PLAN_NUM,
row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ACCT_ID ORDER BY PLAN_NUM) a1
FROM ACCT_PLAN
WHERE PLAN_STATUS_CD='ACTIVE')

SELECT
ad.SRC_EXTRACT_DT,
ad.ACCT_ID,
LISTAGG(LPAD(PLAN_NUM, 5, '0') ||  LPAD(RMAN_PYMT_CNT, 2, '0'),';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ad.ACCT_ID) AS PLAN_INFO 
FROM ACCT_DLY ad
JOIN rn
ON ad.ACCT_ID = rn.ACCT_ID
WHERE rn.a1 <= 10
group by ad.SRC_EXTRACT_DT,
ad.ACCT_ID;